# How to make Chakra UI box/flex item to take 100% width

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, width, chakra-ui

I'm having a problem with the Chakra UI box or flex items (not sure which one is causing the problem). I can't make them take 100% width on tablets and mobiles. The only way I managed to make it work is by defining VW width but that's not responsive on all devices.

How it looks now:
[image]

how it should look:
[image]
Code (the part of code that's not working is the first ternary option):

```
enter code here
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Flex, useMediaQuery } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Section from 'components/section/Section'
import HoursCellList from 'components/schedule/hours/HoursCellList'
import DaysCellList from './days/DaysCellList'
import EventsComponent from 'components/schedule/events/EventsComponent'
import MobileDaysCellList from './days/MobileDaysCellList'
import MobileEventsFlex from 'components/schedule/events/MobileEventFlex'
interface Props {}

const ScheduleComponent = (props: Props) => {
  
    const [isSmallScreen] = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 1350px)')



    const [mobileClickedDay, setMobileClickedDay] = useState<number>(0)
    return (
        <Section isGray heading="Schedule" id="schedule">
            <Box py={['2', '4', '8']}>
                {isSmallScreen ? (
                    <Flex justifyItems="stretch">
                        <Box>
                            <HoursCellList isMobile={isSmallScreen} />
                        </Box>
                        <Flex flexDirection="column" bg="#fff" flex="1">
                            <MobileDaysCellList clickedDay={mobileClickedDay} onClick={setMobileClickedDay} />
                            <MobileEventsFlex clickedDay={mobileClickedDay} />
                        </Flex>
                    </Flex>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <HoursCellList isMobile={isSmallScreen} />
                        <Flex w="1200px" bg="#fff">
                            <DaysCellList />
                            <EventsComponent />
                        </Flex>
                    </>
                )}
            </Box>
        </Section>
    )
}

export default ScheduleComponent
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

All other page components are in Section component as children, and they work fine, just this one is causing the problem...
Section component code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import SectionHeading from './SectionHeading'
import { Box, Center, BoxProps } from '@chakra-ui/react'

interface Props {
    heading?: string
    subHeading?: string
    isGray?: boolean
    id?: string
    children: React.ReactNode
}
type SectionProps = Props & BoxProps
const Section = ({ children, heading = '', subHeading = '', isGray = false, id = '', ...props }: SectionProps) => {
    return (
        <Center>
            <Box
                bg={isGray ? 'primaryBg' : 'secondaryBg'}
                color="primaryText"
                zIndex="0"
                w="100%"
                pt={['47px', '56px', '70px']}
                pb={['12', '16', '24']}
                minHeight="100vh"
                d="flex"
                alignItems="center"
                {...props}
                id={id}
            >
                <Box maxWidth="1366px" mx="auto" px={['15px', '43px', '83px']}>
                    <Box>
                        <SectionHeading heading={heading} subHeading={subHeading} />
                        {children}
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Center>
    )
}

export default Section
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I can't believe that the problem is such a stupid thing haha,

Problem is fixed by adding w='100%' in Section component next to maxWidth='1366px'

Comment: Good question and good answer nonetheless